# Image name metadata is wrong after drag and drop

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, metadata

I have an image manager application in which I allow drag-and-drop. When dragging an image in, I execute this line to get the image's path and name.

```
public bool GetFileName(out string _filename, DrageventArgs E)
{
    _filename = String.Empty;
    Array data = ((System.Windows.Forms.IDataObject)e.Data).GetData("FileName") as Array;
    ...
}
```

The line is taken from [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9017/A-Simple-Drag-And-Drop-How-To-Example), so it might be too advanced for my level, but it worked pretty well and I thought I understood well enough what it did to use it.

However, I'm having issues getting the right image title. I suspect the "FileName" data might be the cause, because when dragging an image called "Phare.jpg", The string I'm getting is

```
"C:\Users\\Public\Pictures\SAMPLE~1\LIGHTH~1.JPG".
```

the "LIGHTH" bit is basically "phare" but in english... at least the first letters. Maybe I'm not pulling the right bit of data? Is there a better way to do this? Is there a different bit of data than "FileName" I could try pulling out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [8.3 file name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename) constructed from normal file name. Most likely whatever software you use to show name of the file uses some interesting mapping of file name to display name OR the non 8.3 name is totally different from 8.3 name is your case (doing `dir C:\Users\\Public\Pictures\SAMPLE~1` in command prompt may show what actual file name is).

You should be able to map 8.3 file name back to regular name with [System.IO.Path.GetFullPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx).

There is chance that you can get image name in other language from image metadata - check out [Image.PropertyItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.propertyitems.aspx) .

Comment: Right.  You might want to mention that System.IO.Path.GetFullPath() converts a short name to a long name.

Comment: When typing  `dir C:\Users\\Public\Pictures\SAMPLE~1` in command prompt I get the full name, but it's still in english. I'm guessing that's the name embedded in the image and not the one appearing in windows explorer.

Comment: @HansPassant, thanks - inlined in the answer. Also added potentially useful call to get properties.